# Header file not giving declarations to functions

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm trying to build a project on Linux. All the other dependencies are building correctly, but when it comes to building the main project I'm having issues with a dependency on ZzipLib (0.13.69). The header file looks as follows:

```
#ifndef _ZZIP_ZZIP_H /* zziplib.h */
#define _ZZIP_ZZIP_H

#include <zzip/types.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//Code

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _ZZIPLIB_H */
```

and is included via:

```
#include "../zziplib-13.69/zzip/zzip.h"
#include "../zziplib-13.69/zzip/lib.h"
```

When it comes to building however, I'm getting function not declared errors for Zziplib functions used in my main file, all of which definitely exists within the 2 header files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to setup any circularities in your `#include` statements?

Comment: You header guards are reserved to the implementation. You need to choose another name. Edit: Ah, nevermind. It's not your header, but theirs. They should fix the header guard.

Comment: Note that `_ZZIP_ZZIP_H` is an illegal symbol.  Remove the leading underscore, or change it to `ONCE_ZZIP_ZZIP_H` (or GUARD or SENTINEL or whatever term you prefer).  If that's nor code, then it's somebody else's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got path elements in your `#include` that shouldn't be there.  You should instead specify an include path using the `-I` option to gcc.

So you code should have this:

```
#include <zzip/zzip.h>
#include <zzip/lib.h>
```

And your compilation command should look something like this:

```
gcc -I ../zziplib-13.69/ {other options}
```

Comment: Probably should be `#include "zzip/zzip.h"` with straight-quotes, instead of using system header angle-bracket.

Comment: @Eljay As far as I know the recommended/preferred guideline is to use quotes for your own project's header files, angle brackets for system and external libraries.

Comment: System and standard headers:  yes.  Installed external libraries, like Boost:  yes.  External libraries that are part of your source tree or a peer thereof:  no.  In all cases, relative pathing (or absolute pathing) in `#include` is always a bad terrible egregious mistake.